# Used input class to grab name, then pass to JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

Using a repeater to display a list. In this list are comment box and submit btn. I want the user to enter data and click the corresponding submit btn.
ERROR:
JavaScript runtime error: Sys.Net.WebServiceFailedException: The server method 'CommentBox' failed with the following error: System.InvalidOperationException-- Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'CommentBoxContents'.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var commentBoxData = $('.' + CommentBoxId).val();
```

to

```
var commentBoxData = $('#' + CommentBoxId).val();
```

You are selecting the element with `class` of CommentBoxId. Use `#` for id instead.